# Text editors and IDE cannot write properly ɑ̃ ɛ̃ ɑ̃ ɔ̃ œ̃ character

Tags: intellij-idea, utf-8, phpstorm, sublimetext3

I tried many IDE: Sublime Text, PhpStorm, Notepad++

When I paste the **ɑ̃** character I got `a^` (2 chars)

[image]

Same happens with other chars such as **ɛ̃ ɑ̃ ɔ̃ œ̃**

I tried to change UTF-8, UTF18, ISO etc... All IDE did change the **ɑ̃** into 2 chars !

Any idea ?

Comment: `I tried to change UTF-8, UTF18, ISO` ***what*** did you try to change exactly?

Answer (score 1):

In my case it works fine:
[image] (Indeed, it's treated as two characters, like you can delete only the first/second "part" by backspace, but it's displaying correctly)

I think it's the problem of font. You may try my fallback font [Inziu Iosevka](https://be5invis.github.io/Iosevka/) which may probably support those characters better.

Other characters test:
[image]
Fine.

My complete font setting (IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate):
[image]

Hope it help.